# Is emitting events synchronously incorrect?

Tags: javascript, api, events

> in any system that will ever exist, attaching listeners is async.
>   any system that ever uses an event driven style will emit events async.
>   there is no compromise to make there it's a mistake to do so any other way

Should event emission always be asynchronous?

Comment: Is that a quote from somewhere?

Comment: @missingno It's just my quoting a colleague.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `.forEach` be considered an event system of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some use cases of where event emitters are used synchronously because there is a taste for the design pattern, but I think it makes little sense. You should always try to invoke a function as you invoke every other function if that's essentially what your application is doing. Sync event emitters are not entirely uncommon but I do think they are a bad design choice and should be avoided.

I should probably also mention that sync event emitters make sense in JavaScript when you want to simulate an event occurring for the purpose of testing, but I do think it should otherwise be driven by an async event emitter.

Answer (score 1):

It should.

An event emitter is nothing else than a large loop which calls a number of functions for a given event(string). Imagine there are thousands or hundreds of thousands bound listeners(functions) for an event and we need to dispatch that event type. If that dispatch happens synchronously we would hang and screw our whole application until all functions were called. Since event emitters often go hand in hand with loosely coupled architectures, this would be horrific.

There must be some kind of asynchrony in this progress.

Comment: `dispatchEvent` is synchronous. Node's `EventEmitter` is synchronous

Comment: @Raynos: that means my example in this post would apply for node?

Comment: [`Communications.dispatch`](https://github.com/jAndreas/BarFoos/blob/master/development/plugins/core_plugin_communication.js#L33) is synchronous

Comment: @Raynos: true, I only have the whole call covered by a `setTimeout`. But its no good design nonetheless. `dispatch` should use timeouts itself to fire all those listeners I guess.

Comment: @jAndy and you think adding a delay of at least 10 milliseconds between each event handler invocation is a good thing?

Comment: It just never made sense to call it an event system in the first place, even if the invocation pattern makes sense in any of your use cases.

Comment: @Raynos: definately. Or.. we need to be precise. in an UI environment (browser) its for sure a very, very good idea to guarantee responsiveness for the user regardless what happens, which is UI no1 rule. On a server, it might be less of a topic. I think I'll go even further and use some runnaway-timer to fire listeners, which means, fire as many listeners as possible within a timeframe of like 100ms, then timeout for 25 and repeat that until we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it shouldn't.

Just because you are emitting events doesn't mean the emitting or processing need to be asynchronous.

Your event processing shouldn't depend on running synchronous.

As an example most GUI frameworks are eventbased and run in a single thread.

Comment: GUIs take inputs from the user asynchronously. The whole point of using event driven programming in a GUI is to improve perceived responsiveness. You might process my events in order in a tight loop on one thread, as happens in JavaScript event processing, but you are not preventing me from queueing up multiple events to be processed. You release me, the user, the event emitter, as soon as you can. I can make multiple clicks in the browser while you are still processing the first one. Asycn emitters are not the same as concurrent execution of listeners.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I disagree with the responses. I think the correct answer is that there is no always correct answer. People have cited reasons for asynchrony, and those are valid, but there are other cases where synchrony is preferable. I use a PubSub library that conveniently has publish() and publishSync() methods to allow for both (the default being asynchronous).

One case where you want synchrony is when you want all listeners to have access to the current state at the time of the event.

As to the argument that asynchronous calls are non-blocking so allow single-threaded UI updates (as in JavaScript), this is true to a point. If you have a continuously updating UI (that is, animated), it doesn't much matter if you do something time-consuming now vs. time-consuming "later"; either way if it is time-consuming it will block the animation and drop the frame rate. I sometimes prefer to have all this synchronous, because there are benefits to run-to-completion, and I can more easily test and profile to make sure *all* my listeners are cumulatively processing the event(s) in 1/fps time. Async listeners not only pass the buck but make the profiling of this much trickier.

There's a difference between "not knowing" what listeners are invoked in the sense that you want at construction-time or compile-time for components to be unaware of each other vs. "not knowing" in the sense that you aren't able to know what other components exist in your application and who has registered listeners. Arguably even if you're the sole programmer there are advantages to pretending not to know in the latter sense (e.g. this allows you to not assume too much about future changes to your own code base), but then its also arguable that you *should*, as a human being, know that there are basically these 5 components registering a dozen listeners to do so much work, as opposed to there are a potentially infinite number of listeners doing who knows what work. The latter is often extreme (premature?) optimization. The idea that simply making calls async *allows* one to not know the latter is flawed. Async doesn't magically buy infinite processing time. Nor can individual listeners know more than the emitter, or the programmer, about how much time they are allowed to process. (Well, they could if the event system includes this info, but that's beyond the pubsub pattern.)